# How to store balances on goods in the sections of the goods and dates in Django?

Tags: django

I'm new in django. There is a task to write an application for the movement of residues in the warehouse. The application must be able to receive data in the context of a product or goods in the context of a date or a date interval, or on a specific date.

**Theoretically, I understand the structure of the model:**

1. Product model
2. Model Document (Income / Expense Document)
3. Model DocumentRow (Tabular part of the document)
4. Transactions model (intermediate table for storing balances; balances for each month should be recorded here).

For paragraph 4, you need to record balances by month and product. To keep the data in this table up to date, I need to recalculate all balances after this date when writing the DocumentRow on a specific date.

Example:

1. 10/01/2018 Arrival 10
2. 10/15/2018 Arrival 20
3. 12.12.2018 Consumption 10

Entries in the Transactions table (Month, Start Balance, End Balance)

1. 10/01/2018 0 10
2. 10/01/2018 10 30
3. 12/01/2018 30 20

***I don’t know whether it is possible to implement this on django, in fact I need an analog of a turnover balance sheet, I need your opinion or a new look at this problem***

Comment: Of course this is possible. Just fetch the last entry when you have a new transaction, calculate the values for the new entry and save.

Answer (score 0):

You can override predefined model method `save()` in yours models, how in this example:

```
from django.db import models

class Example(models.Model):
myfield = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Here you can put your logic
    # On this case I adding a prefix and sufix to myfield
    self.myfield = "{}{}{}".format('prefix ', self.myfield, ' suffix')
    # Now call the "real" save() method.
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```